# MYsql Shut down often for no reason and unable restart after

Tags: mysql, error-handling

```
150505 16:57:01 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
150505 16:58:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150505 16:58:01 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150505 16:58:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150505 16:58:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150505 16:58:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150505 16:58:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
150505 16:58:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150505 16:58:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
150505 16:58:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150505 16:58:01 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
150505 16:58:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150505 16:58:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150505 16:58:01 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150505 16:58:01 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Above is mysql error log, sometime mysql will just crash, and I want to do a restart on the service, it will not able to start,the error is something like 
the "unknown instance" error.

Anyone got any idea what the error above is about and how to solve it, I tried google but seems to not able find the answer.

**Thanks!**

Comment: Do you have enough RAM/swap space available? You could try decreasing innodb_buffer_pool_size to 64 MB.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question searching for an answer myself, my server's `/var/log/mysql/error.log` had very similar statements to yours. Running `dmesg | tail -20` revealed the culprit: the OS ran out of memory and killed `mysqld`:

```
[835661.446277] Out of memory: Kill process 1024 (mysqld) score 91 or sacrifice child
[835661.446912] Killed process 1024 (mysqld) total-vm:901544kB, anon-rss:92332kB, file-rss:0kB
[835661.488337] init: mysql main process (1024) killed by KILL signal
```

Now to figure out why memory ran out, on this newer server, with twice as much RAM as the one it's replacing, which never did this...